# Android - In app billing V3. Is it safe to call getPurchases on the UI thread at all times?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing, networkonmainthread, android-inapp-purchase

I want to retrieve the list of purchased items for my application. We only have the `getPurchases` API to do that. Its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) says:

> Because the Google Play client now caches In-app Billing information locally on the device, you can use the Version 3 API to query for this information more frequently, for example through a getPurchases call. Unlike with previous versions of the API, many Version 3 API calls will be serviced through cache lookups instead of through a network connection to Google Play, which significantly speeds up the API's response time.

However, it is not clear from that statement if that method can potentially perform a network call in order to retrieve the info. If that is the case, my app will crash as for now I call that method from the UI Thread only.

Is it safe to call that method from the UI Thread?

Comment: I would imagine the billing library's lookup is already async, that message appears more to inform you that often it is able to respond QUICKER due to the caches is all

Comment: getPurchases returns a Bundle. So, if it can be async, that means the main thread will be blocked until the Bundle is returned which is not what I want. I wonder if I need to go over the trouble of spawning a new thread and call that method inside this new thread then. That is why I need to know if getPurchases can perform asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've decided to play safe and use RxJava to spawn a thread and send the result back to the main thread instead. Even if it is the case today that that method does not perform a network call I don't want to assume it will always be that way since the docs really don't say anything about it.